# How to manage a path with numbers after backslashes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am using Python 3.3 on Windows 7.

Here is the problem.

When I have a filename starting with a number it changes wrong.

For example:

```
>>> 'E:\DOCUMENTS\1.jpg'
'E:\\DOCUMENTS\x01.jpg'
```

I am aware that I can fix it manually by adding an escaping backslash.

```
>>> 'E:\DOCUMENTS\\1.jpg'
'E:\\DOCUMENTS\\1.jpg'
```

Or by adding "r" in front of the string.

```
>>> r'E:\DOCUMENTS\1.jpg'
'E:\\DOCUMENTS\\1.jpg'
```

But I cannot do it manually, because I don't know what the path will be.

What are the possible solutions?

UPDATE:
As @Blender suggested, I was going to post the code. When I rewrote it, I realized that originally there was a mistake, that leaded me to a wrong conclusion. As far as I have understood, the described above situation, when it is necessary to make a string with a path raw dynamically does not happen. It can only happen when the path is written manually.

```
import os
from PIL import Image as PIL
from PIL import ImageTk

def searchforimages(dir):
    imagelist=[]
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        fileabspath=os.path.join(dir,file)
        try:
            # the problem was here originally, but now it is ok.
            # since "fileabspath" get passes as a raw string,
            # so there is no problem for PIL.open() to open it
            PIL.open(fileabspath)
            imagelist.append(fileabspath)
        except:
            continue
    return imagelist

searchforimages('E:\photos')

#the problem only happens, when path is written manually
path='E:\photos\1.jpg'
PIL.open(path)
```

So now I just want to confirm, the problem when it is necessary to make a string with a path raw dynamically never really happens, does it?

Comment: It's not a "fix": this is literally how the string is represented. `\1` is `\x01`. Just out of curiosity, how does this problem even arise? Why does it matter that you don't know what the path is beforehand?

Comment: I want to open images with PIL module and those files, which names start with digits, I can't open.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How are you getting these names?

Comment: I use os.listdir and os.path.abspath.

Comment: If there is something like 'E:\DOCUMENTS\1.jpg' I get such an error.   
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1974, in open
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\DOCUMENTS\x01.jpg'

Comment: Can you post your *exact* code (or the shortest example that reproduces the problem, without hard-coding the path)? This could very well be a bug in PIL.

Comment: >Blender   I have added the code to the question and have found that I was wrong. It seems the problem described in the question never happens.

Answer (score 1):

`\` only matters when it is used in string literal.

```
>>> path = input() # `a\n\1` in the following line is typed by me (user).
a\n\1
>>> path
'a\\n\\1'
```

Comment: Specifically, it only has its special behavior when used in a string literal. When a backslash comes from anywhere else, that's just a real backslash, not the start of an escape sequence. It still matters in that it's a part of the string.